# VS2019 project loads a dll at runtime istead of using the static library

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2019, lib

I have setup my project with precompiled static libraries.
[image: lib name]
[image: include folder]
[image]

Yet when I run the project it'll try to load a dll:

> 'Project1.exe' (Win32) : Chargé 'D:\Projects\VisualStudio\Dll1\Debug\MinHook.x86.dll'.

I can't find any reference to this dll from the project's settings  or inside the .sln and .vcxproj  files, yet loading my dll without `MinHook.x86.dll` will fail. Any idea where that could come from?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that *MinHook.x86.lib* is static?

Comment: The release archive on github has .lib and .dll, so I suppose it is. I'll check this out.

Comment: If there's a *.dll*, then it's not.

Answer (score 0):

`MinHook.x86.lib` is 'import library' used by MSVC to load DLL. To link statically you should use `libMinHook-x86-v141-mt.lib` static library.